# Portrait image resizing in java with imgscalr, but the final output is landscape. How to guarantee it stays the same orientation?

Tags: java, resize, image-manipulation, thumbnails, scaletransform

I am using imgscalr to create scale my images in a Grails application.   Here is the code:

```
BufferedImage sourceImg = ImageIO.read(new File("/tmp" + File.separator + filename))
BufferedImage destImg = null

if(sourceImg.height >= sourceImg.width){
    destImg = Scalr.resize(sourceImg, Scalr.Method.AUTOMATIC, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_HEIGHT, 800) 
}
else{
    destImg = Scalr.resize(sourceImg, Scalr.Method.AUTOMATIC, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH, 800)
}

File newFile = new File("/tmp/processed" + File.separator + filename)
String formatName = foto.nomeArquivo.substring(foto.nomeArquivo.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
ImageIO.write(imgDestino, formatName.toUpperCase(), newFile)
```

Please do not mind about formatName so far.... I am still testing the imgscalr library.

All my images end in landscape orientation. I am developing in a Mac OS.

Thanks

Comment: Felipe,

I am the author of imgscalr; what I think might be happening is that your picture is actually in landscape mode, but the ORIENTATION Exif data in the image indicates that it should be rotated, so when you view it in a picture viewer, it shows it in portrait mode (but was actually taken with the camera turned sideways).

imgscalr currently doesn't consider EXIF data from the original image when generating a scaled copy, but I think it needs to. I've filed an issue to try and address this in a future release.

Comment: Riyad, thank you very much for your comments. I tried with some other images, and you must be right. Some of them imgscalr are being scaled in the correct orientation. So the problem is with the original file indeed. But if you can work around this would be really great. I am trying to have a 100% java solution, instead of relying on ImageMagick. Tks anyway

Comment: Felipe, I'll get that feature in shortly; it requires a bit of good engineering and thinking so it's not a quick fix, but I'll make sure it gets in there and done in a nice/tight way. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Felipe, I have found a workaround for you that should work quickly and easily until I can find a way of addressing this without bloating the API. This library can do a lossless transform based on the EXIF orientation information (http://mediachest.sourceforge.net/mediautil/) you can do that THEN give the image to imgscalr to scale it for you.

Comment: That´s great Riyad. Thanks so much for the help and the good work on imgscalr.

Comment: Felipe, just wanted to let you know that imgscalr 3.2 was released (https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr) and added manual rotation support (among other cool things). I am working on imgscalr 4.0 right now which is adding, via an optional ext JAR library, support for what will be a new AUTOMATIC rotation mode that utilizes Phil Harvey's ExifTool to read the EXIF from the image -- this will require an external install of ExifTool but it is open source, runs on all platforms and is the most robust EXIF library bar none. The addon library will also provide an interface to ET for anyone to use